# Cannot run peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, peer

When I start my network ( `./byfn.sh up` ) I get the error, that I can't run peer:

```
Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, folder "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" does not exist
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
```

What can I do to solve my problem?

- I deleted the samples and installed it again
- removed images
- stopped and started docker
- checked all the requirements - all are installed

Comment: try to delete the volume using docker volume prune

Comment: @AdityaJoshi thanks. I used your command, and the docker volume is also deleted, but I still have the same error as I mentioned in my question :(

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it now:

@AdityaJoshi thank you for your suggestion (first Step).

So what I did:

1. `docker volume prune`
2. `docker ps -aq | xargs docker kill`
3. `docker ps -aq | xargs docker rm`
4. `./byfn.sh up`